# Jest transformIgnorePatterns not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I have spent a long time looking at other questions about this and looking at other projects on Github but none of the answers seem to work for me.

I am loading a third party library in my project, and when running Jest tests I get the error

```
export default portalCommunication;
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

> 1 | import portalCommunication from 'mathletics-portal-communication-service';
```

I have tried updating my Jest config in many ways to get it to transpile this library but I always get the same error.

This is my current jest.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '\\.(css|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
        '\\.svg$': '<rootDir>/test/mocks/svg-mock.js'
    },
    setupFiles: ['./test/test-setup.js'],
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!mathletics-portal-communication-service)'
    ]
};
```

I have also tried adding the transform property to run babel-jest against this mathletics-portal-communication-service directory.

Please help!

Comment: you probably need to configure babel.

Comment: My project has babel set up and working fine, is there something special I would need to do for Jest? I thought it used babel-jest automatically?

Comment: See related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75089099/8285811)

Answer (score 59):

The `transformIgnorePatterns` didn't work for me until I changed my `.babelrc` to `babel.config.js`, like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
};
```

as seen on this comment: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6229#issuecomment-403539460

Comment: Do you know if a `.babelrc` or `babel.config.js` file is absolutely necessary? I'm trying to get mine working with just a `transformIgnorePatterns` declaration in my `package.json`

Comment: Looking at the linked github issue, it seems like it won't work in the package.json either, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: This response is underrated!! I had been bumping my head for several hours until I saw this! Heck this should be in the docs!

Comment: Weird that .babelrc doesn't work while babel.config,js does.

Comment: thank you, you save my time!

Comment: is there an issue with making the filename change? I mean, will this fix tests but potentially break something else?

Comment: It took my the whole day to fix this error, installing this babel package and adding the babel.config.js solved it for me

Answer (score 13):

Another team at my org added some common module. This was not transpiled and so the issue.

I followed this: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration#whats-your-use-case

1. Converted my `.babelrc` to `babel.config.json`
2. in jest config added this:
   `transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!(@companyName)/).*/'],`

This solved my problem.

Comment: I saw someone say to add this to package.json.. uhh. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for this! It's a subtle line in the babel documentation, but (apparently) Babel will not compile your `node_modules` unless you have a `babel.config.json` file present. Super unexpected behavior, in my opinion, but at least I got it working

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround for now I have changed my config to use the `moduleNameMapper` option to load a mock class for that library instead. I would have preferred to use `transformIgnorePatterns` instead so would still appreciate any ideas.

New config:

```
module.exports = {
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '\\.(css|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
        '\\.svg$': '<rootDir>/test/mocks/svg-mock.js',
        'mathletics-portal-communication-service': '<rootDir>/test/mocks/mathletics-portal-communication-service-mock.js'
    },
    setupFiles: ['./test/test-setup.js']
};
```

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for my case as well

Answer (score 5):

Adding trailing slash fix this for me:

```js
{
    // ...
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!mathletics-portal-communication-service/)'
    ]
};
```

Answer (score -4):

It might be your use of `rootDir`. Try:

```
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(mathletics-portal-communication-service))"
    ]
```