# Jest with Craco config with esbuild-jest transform SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' on @bundled-es-modules"

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, transform, esmodules

I am using Create React APP created an application, while using craco to override the configuration.

I am trying to use Jest to run some test however got this issue

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' on "node_modules/@bundled-es-modules/statuses"

I am aware of that I need to transform the @bundled-es-modules to CommonJS module.
from this link https://github.com/mswjs/msw/issues/1810
[Jest encountered an unexpected token - SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70817646/jest-encountered-an-unexpected-token-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export)

I added

```
transform: {
                '\\.[jt]sx?$': 'esbuild-jest',
                '\\.[jt]s?$': 'esbuild-jest',
            },
transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(@bundled-es-modules)/)/'],
```

or

```
preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-babel',
transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(@bundled-es-modules)/)/'],
```

in transformIgnorePatterns I tried add  or without it, either works.

in my craco.config.js however it didn't resolve my issue.

anyone can help me with that?

here is my craco.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
    jest: {
        configure: {
            testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
            moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json'],
            preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-babel',
            transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(@bundled-es-modules)/)/'],
        },
    },
};
```

error details is

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    xxx/node_modules/@bundled-es-modules/statuses/index-esm.js:172
    export {
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/msw/src/core/utils/logging/serializeResponse.ts:1:22)
```